# How to use the full height and width of a SettingsFlyout in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a Windows 8.1 application with a settings flyout which will open when you click a custom setting in the settings charms bar.

However my content inside the settings flyout is not using the full height/width of the settings flyout instead has a uniform margin across all corners. The following picture displays the same.

[image]

For better understanding I have put black and red backgrounds. The black background is for SettingsFlyout, the red is for the StackPanel inside the Flyout. I have set the StackPanel height and width to the actualheight and actualwidth of the flyout
Here's the XAML

```
<SettingsFlyout
x:Name="AccountsSettingsFlyoutElement"
x:Class="Something.AccountsSettingsFlyout"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Background="Black"
mc:Ignorable="d"
IconSource="Assets/SmallLogo.png"
Title="Accounts"
d:DesignWidth="346">

<!-- This StackPanel acts as a root panel for vertical layout of the content sections -->
<StackPanel Background="Red"
            Width="{Binding ElementName=AccountsSettingsFlyoutElement, Path=ActualWidth}"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=AccountsSettingsFlyoutElement, Path=ActualHeight}">
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource SettingsFlyoutSectionStyle}">
        <TextBlock Text="Accounts"
                   x:Uid="AccountsSettings_Title"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   Style="{StaticResource SettingTitleStyle}" />

    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

As you can see the red is not covering the whole of the black region. I want to create a UI like this.

[image]

Now if you notice at the bottom of the above figure. The Add An Account Button covers the entire width of the Flyout.

How do I achieve a UI similar to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActualHeight is not a dependency property so the binding is probably not working. The way to 'bind' the height is to use a SizeChanged event handler such as this.

```
    private void ScrollViewer_OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        YourGrid.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
        YourGrid.Height = e.NewSize.Height;
    }
```

The SettingsFlyout Style has a padding built-in. To use the total area for your content, set the padding property to 0.

```
<SettingsFlyout x:Class="ApplicationSettings.SettingsFlyout1"
            Padding="0" ...
```

Last thing, to set the correct size, use the size of the content presenter.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                Grid.Row="1"
                SizeChanged="ScrollViewer_OnSizeChanged"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        ContentTransitions="{Binding TemplateSettings.ContentTransitions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

[image: Full-size settings flyout]

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked fine just after I set the padding to 0. But I didn't understand the other part of your answer. I don't think the SizeChanged and ContentPresenter are required. Could you explain why that is required?

Answer (score 2):

SettingsFlyout is inherited from ContentControl therefore you need change only next properties for fill full section :

```
<SettingsFlyout .....
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                Padding="0">
    <Grid Background="blue" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        ....
    </Grid>
</SettingsFlyout>
```

Comment: Sir @Mikhail where can I put those line,in a Style than affect it the the Flyout??